# Print html file in C#, window

Tags: c#, html, printing, window, uri

- I have Window Client , and server
- Client call server to get html (by string).
- Client edit html file, and want to PRINT IT. Real print- paper, offline.

=> almost everyone said, for html printing, use WebBrowser.

At first, I want to print html string directly, by using WebBrowser.DocumentText.

It didn't work. 
=>

```
WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();
WebBrowser.DocumentText = (my html strings. like "<html>contents</html>";)
WebBrowser.Print();
```

so I'm trying to write html string to text and create aaa.html

I made it Successfully, but then..

I tried to use

```
private void PrintHelpPage()
{
    // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
    WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

    // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
    webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

    // Set the Url property to load the document.
    webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(@"\\myshare\help.html");
}

private void PrintDocument(object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

    // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
}
```

I don't know how I get Uri(@"\myshare\help.html" );

my file's uri...

somebody helps... i searched and searched, but I can't find anything.

I tried to take it on my desktop and do for test
Uri(@"file:\\C:\Users\Mine\Desktop\aaa1.html" ); and it's not working...

---

I did one more try

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/08eaef5d-1177-4aec-a521-4e5eb1c22640/printdocumentprint-print-a-website?forum=csharpgeneral

```
 using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Printing;


  private Font printFont;
  private StreamReader reader;
  string url = "http://www.google.com";
  WebResponse response = null;


  private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
  {
   float linesPerPage = 0;
   float yPos = 0;
   int count = 0;
   float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
   float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
   string line = null;

   // Calculate the number of lines per page.
   linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
    printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

   // Print each line of the file.
   while (count < linesPerPage &&
    ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
   {
    yPos = topMargin + (count *
     printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
    ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black,
     leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
    count++;
   }

   // If more lines exist, print another page.
   if (line != null)
    ev.HasMorePages = true;
   else
    ev.HasMorePages = false;
  }


private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
  try 
  {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    response = request.GetResponse();
    reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

   try 
   {
    printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler
     (this.pd_PrintPage);
    pd.Print();
   } 
   finally 
   {
    reader.Close();
   }
  } 
  catch(Exception ex) 
  {
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
 }
```

and on paper it shows html all lines.

like this- < html > blah blah < / html >

Comment: does it work when printing some other html page, eg "https://stackoverflow.com"?

Comment: webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(@"stackoverflow.com");   // or https://stackoverflow.com
error said :   UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined: stackoverflow.com
System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString, Boolean dontEscape)
System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString)

Comment: sorry, I actually meant the whole URL, the one which starts with "https://"

Comment: yeah I tried adding " https://"  too. and it didn't work and got same error